# Problem on npm error shown on verwsion v8.15.1 not supported

Tags: node.js, blockchain

On linux facing problem when we use any npm command
`ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v8.15.1
You'll need to upgrade to a newer Node.js version in order to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

I try on check version npm and install npm-g @latest
`

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your NodeJs version to latest one and then run NPM

To downlaod latest node
https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: After this also facing same problem